# Autocomplete commands not working gnome 40

Tags: linux, terminal, gnome, autocomplete, manjaro

When I start typing a command, the terminal gives me suggestions from previous commands. But when I press the `tab` key it says: `zsh: do you wish to see all 3536 possibilities (3536 lines)?` Is there a specific key combination that will autocomplete the command?

[image: Picture of the terminal]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tab is used for tab complete which is a different feature altogether. It's to complete whatever command you are typing based on the available possibilities, for example, completing a directory name after only typing in the first few letters. It does not draw from your shell history.

The behavior you are looking for is achieved using the Right Arrow key.

Comment: Thank you so much!